# Override default flexbox child element being 100% height

Tags: css, height, flexbox

Any flex child element has 100% height (more specifically, the cross-direction) of the flex element. Is there a way to override this to "shrink", or is the only way to put your content as a grandchild nested in two flex ancestors?

html

```
.original
  .parent
    .content
```

css

```
.original {
 display:flex;
  justify-content;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
}
.content {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [flex-wrap: wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/) to the .original.